Run coverage test with dotCover on ASP.NET application
I have written a series of tests against the front end of my web application. I really wanted to know what my test coverage looked like, so I downloaded and installed ReSharper and dotCover. These work great with the unit tests associated with my application library, but I am really struggling to get the coverage results of my front end code.
I've tried:

Launching the application (without debugging) in IIS Express within Visual Studio, right clicking my front end tests and selecting "Cover Unit Tests". The tests complete successfully, but the coverage still shows 0%.

IIS Express option from dotCover's new run configuration:  
Extensions -> ReSharper -> Cover -> Cover Application  
IIS Express -> Next  
Configuration file: <solutionFolder>\.vs\<projectName>\config\applicationhost.config
Site: <ProjectName> 
Open URL: https://localhost:44377/  
Save  
Process Filters: Default  
Start  
Right click front end tests and select "Cover Unit Tests".  
The tests fail and the application returns the error "HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime"

Launching an external instance of IIS express via PowerShell.
Borrowing from this answer, I created a PowerShell script to launch IIS Express. The application starts, but I get the same "HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime" error.


I have installed the .NET 8 hosting bundle in addition to the SDK. I have both Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.6 and Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.6.
The application runs just fine when starting with Visual Studio. I'm convinced that it's just something wrong with my "Launch Settings" when I try to start IIS Express with dotCover or PowerShell. However, I can't determine the exact issue.

I feel compelled to down vote my own question. I'm still working through it, but I think I've figured it out. I just didn't understand how to properly use dotCover. A YouTube video by JetBrains was very helpful.

Seems I was missing a few environment variables. I added the following to my dotCover run configuration:
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
LAUNCHER_ARGS=exec <path to ASP dll>
LAUNCHER_PATH=C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Then IIS Express started as expected. Then I ran my playwright tests. When complete, you click the "Take snapshot and wait" button to save the snapshot.
Now I just need to figure out how to run my library and front end tests via command line. Right now, I'm running each individually and then having to manually merge the two results. I'd like to make this one process using dotCover command line.

Hi, there's a merge command that allows to merge reports automatically, please refer to recently posted blog post about dotCover CLT - https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2024/06/20/dotcover-command-line-tools-for-automation-testing-code-coverage/#merging-multiple-reports-into-one

@truefar - Thanks for the info. I am familiar with and using the merge command. I was just having a little trouble getting the IIS Express coverage to work. I'm happy to say, it all working now and I am slowly increasing my overall code coverage.
